# Class AdoNetAppender is missing from log4net.Appender

Tags: c#, log4net-configuration

All my searching seems to indicate that log4net.dll that comes with the NuGet Package log4net 2.0.8 should have a class [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_AdoNetAppender.htm). Mine doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?

[image: where did AdoNetAppender go?]

[image]

Comment: .NET Core 2.0.0, on Windows.